# How to partition my drive to separate the OS and my files after installation?

Tags: partitioning

I have installed Ubuntu 13.10. I have my files saved on a separate hard drive.  Now I want to put them back on my computer so I can access them in Ubuntu but I am nervous.

During installation I erased the drive (I thought it would just replace Windows and leave my partitioned drive D reserved for files alone, but it didn't).

I would like to partition my drive and use one partition for my files and the other for the OS like I had in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the best is to partition the drive during install, or, in your case, leave the partitions as they are and install Ubuntu on the partion where windows is (replace it).

By default, Ubuntu uses the whole disk for installation. In your case you should have done the installation steps untill you can choose "installation type" and choose "something else" there. Then remove the windows partition and create a swap partition of, let's say 1GB and an ext4 partition to install the system on (mountpoint `/`).

To make the existing data partition available in the newly installed system, select it (in the same window) and choose "Change" (next to +-); keep the same file system as it already is and give it mountpoint `/data` or something you like. Do **NOT** format the partition! That way it would have been as you planned.

In this situation you can choose: do a reinstall and a repartitioning, or just copy your existing data to `/home/"yourname"`. You could of course resize the partition to be able to create your data partition, but it is more "clean" to reinstall; you just installed Ubuntu and probably did not do too much work afterwards. All should take no more than just 30 minutes.

here are a few links to screenshots:

choose "something else"
[image]

remove existing partitions:
[image]

create new partitions (in your case somthing like 1x 20GB for Ubuntu, 2gb for swap, the rest for `/data` (the picture shows adding the swap partition)

Start with the system partition, mountpoint `/`, then the data partition, `/data`, and finish with the swap partition. If you do it like that, Ubuntu will set the "type of the new partition" automatically correct.
[image]

and ready to install:
[image]`

Comment: I thought I was doing what you mentioned.  The "something else" option is not well documented.  I am now currently confused with mounted, swap, extended, ext2, lvmz.flags, etc.  I have downloaded gparted and see the screen but???? what do I download to do a screen capture so I can show you what I have going on.  I am afraid to plug in my external drives.  I only have one copy of pics on one drive (75 gig)  and another of music of about (50 gig.)   I am using a EEpc with about a 160 gig hd.

Comment: If I am to reinstall??  where is the downloaded version on this hard drive or do I need to compleatly do this over again.  And?? will it just replace the drive or do I need to delete and clear the drive and then reinstall from my pen drive?

Comment: @user254555 I would do a reinstall, I guess you do not have sensitive data on your drive right now? a complete install does not take too much time. I will try to put a few (links to) screenshots here