# Want To Completely Install Ubuntu As Only OS But Dont Know What Happens To Files

Tags: files, backup, system-installation, transfer

I would like to know how to get my files( Music, Videos, Etc..) to be on Ubuntu when I get rid of Windows OS.

From reading this site I get the impression that if I completely use Ubuntu as my Os and use my entire drive for this but I would like to keep my files as well. A friend recommended me to use Linux since Windows is turning crap. I would appreciate advice on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what, always backup your data. If you switch os and do not have a separate data partition, you will lose everything that is on your disk, you will have to copy it back after installation.

Then the next thing is to decide how you would want your disk to be partitioned; as one big partition + a swap area, or a separate data partition to hold your files. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429213/) to do that

Comment: what exactly is a swap area?

Comment: The short sory: A swap area is a small part of your disk that is used as a temporary "help" for your RAM. The long story: http://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/8208-all-about-linux-swap-space.

The Swap area should be about (roughly) the size of your RAM.

Answer (score 0):

You can remain all your data inside user's folder. Then:

- repartition your drive

  - You should leave ~20Gb for Ubuntu `/` (root fs)
  - Swap area is nearly amount of RAM (I have 4 Gb)
  - 100 Gb for `/home`
  - Leave your old Windows Partition all the remaining space
- Install Ubuntu. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) is the guide.
- During installation, plug Windows partition under `/windows`. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/343370/255292) is the guide
- If you do not want Windows anymore, delete C:\Windows, C:\ProgramData, C:\Program files
- Make links from home:

  ```
  ln -sd /windows/Users/<username>/Documents ~/Documents
  ln -sd /windows/Users/<username>/Downloads ~/Downloads
  ln -sd /windows/Users/<username>/Videos ~/Videos
  ln -sd /windows/Users/<username>/Pictures ~/Pictures
  ln -sd /windows/Users/<username>/Music ~/Music
  ```

  Replace <username> with your username
- Enjoy Ubuntu!

Comment: Probably, there will not be room for an extra 100GB `/home` partition, nor for a 20 GB `/` partition on an existing Windows computer. Furthermore, There is no point in keeping an NTFS partition if you completely switch to Ubuntu. The operation (if there is room for it at all) is a risky one in the hands of an inexperienced user, who did not backup his data.

Comment: But this may turn helpful if asker does not have a place for back up. In my early days I did not have DVD-Rs, nor external drive of 2Tb volume...